# "Error occurred while executing the action getProviderAPIVersionUsage"

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

When using *wso2am-1.10.0* to create a new API using a SOAP endpoint, steps 3/3 completed and testing api just fine i /store. Yet, when coming back to /publisher clicking on the api gives an "`API Publisher - Error`" saying "`Error occurred while executing the action getProviderAPIVersionUsage`". wso2-apigw-errors.log contains only single type of error like this:

> 2016-08-10 14:35:43,004 [-] [pool-199-thread-1] ERROR AsyncDataPublisher Reconnection failed for for tcp://localhost:7614
>   2016-08-10 14:35:46,466 [-] [pool-159-thread-1] ERROR AsyncDataPublisher Reconnection failed for for tcp://localhost:7614
>   2016-08-10 14:35:47,079 [-] [pool-145-thread-1] ERROR AsyncDataPublisher Reconnection failed for for tcp://localhost:7614
>   2016-08-10 14:35:47,367 [-] [pool-113-thread-1] ERROR AsyncDataPublisher Reconnection failed for for tcp://localhost:7614
>   2016-08-10 14:35:47,485 [-] [pool-204-thread-1] ERROR AsyncDataPublisher Reconnection failed for for tcp://localhost:7614
>   2016-08-10 14:35:54,322 [-] [pool-195-thread-1] ERROR AsyncDataPublisher Reconnection failed for for tcp://localhost:7614
>   2016-08-10 14:35:54,346 [-] [pool-175-thread-1] ERROR AsyncDataPublisher Reconnection failed for for tcp://localhost:7614

Answer (score 1):

According to your logs, it seems there is a connection issue. That's why this issue(error log you attached) has occurred. Similar issue can occur when DAS server startup has not completed when APIM starts. If you have enabled API Manager stats please check BAM/DAS configuration and connectivity to those nodes.
If you dont need stats and it enabled by accident you can revert that and try this again.

Comment: ok, but this is a test setup and i dont care about BAM or DAS just yet. and there is nothing more in the logs. i just care about getting rid of this error or at least understand why it comes up. i get it every time i click on this particular API and every time i go to version page for this API in /publisher interface.

Comment: Start the API Manager server and log in to the Admin Dashboard (https://<Server Host>:9443/admin-dashboard). Click Configure Analytics under the Settings section. If check box is selected then uncheck it to disable statistical data publishing. Then stats will be disabled and you will not see this error.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to solve the problem both in the GUI and in the logs. unfortunately i dont have the reputation to mark your answer as correct

Comment: Unfortunately i got this error again! So instead of disabling i decided to enable it, also i upgraded wso2 1.10 till 2.0 and followed this guide. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Configuring+APIM+Analytics is it something i am missing ?